# How to put limit on the size of video being recorded in iOS app?

Tags: size, limit, mpmovieplayercontroller, video-recording, ios8.2

In my app I need to record the video and share in my app's network. I need to put some limit on the size of the video NOT on the duration. I had a look into the documents and I found duration property on which I can put a check for duration but NOT on the size of the video. Is there any way by which it can be achieved? 
I am using "MPMoviePlayerController"

Comment: Seems unlikely that you were using MPMoviePlayerController for __recording__ video.

Comment: @Till I have mentioned that I am using "MPMoviePlayerController". Do you have the solution?

Comment: @Developer: Have you got any solution?